# Where to write test case for this file in initializers in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, exception, functional-testing

I created a common.rb file in intializer folder in rails 2.x app. The code is below

```
def handle_exception &block
  begin
    yield block
  rescue Exception => ex
    logger.error(ex)
    HoptoadNotifier.notify(ex)
  end
end
```

For the above I want to write test case. I guess it should be in functional test. If this is the case. I don't know how should I name it, means I'm confused with (controller name << Base). Do rails run this test case as like other controller test ? Or do we need to add it any where? Since the above code doesn't have class which is inherited from controller, etc.. I will add more info, if you are not clear with my question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `handle_exception` is a global function, so you could just test it using RSpec as follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "common" do

  it "handles exceptions" do
    logger.should_receive( :error )
    HoptaodNotifier.should_receive( :notify )

    handle_exception { raise Exception.new( "This is the error") }
  end

end
```

Comment: Hey @Wolfgang, Thanks for the response. I knew to write test that I already did which is in rails default test suite. My question is which place is suitable to put this test and why ?